# Full Screen Popup (CSS + HTML)

Tags: html, css, dom, web-applications

I'm having some trouble creating a full screen popup for a site I'm working on.
The layout needs to be as follows:

[image]

The head and footer both need to be fixed heights, with the body height expanding and shrinking according to the height of the browser window.

How can I accomplish this?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that the middle section needs to have overflow: scroll for content that is larger than the page's height.

Comment: Something like [this](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)?

Comment: Whoops! Sorry I forgot to mention that the middle section needs to have overflow: scroll for content that is larger than the page's height.

Comment: I am 100% sure [this](http://jsfiddle.net/virendrachandak/cF2Fv/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @DaveChen that's really close to what I need, but can't have the header and footer overlayed onto the body like in the jsFiddle, because they're going to have transparent backgrounds so you can see the page's content underneath the popup. If I use an overlayed header and footer like that, you will be able to see the body text through them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simple option http://jsfiddle.net/jaisonje/mRBJj/ and see the [Scroll Bar sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/jaisonje/mRBJj/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 body, html { height:100%; }
.footer,.header{ position:absolute; top:0; height:50px; background-color:yellow; width:100%;}
.content{ position:absolute; top:50px; bottom:50px; background-color:red;width:100%;}
.footer{ bottom:0; top:auto;}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `box-sizing` property.

Like so:

**[FIDDLE1](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/PGC7D/11/)**  **[FIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/PGC7D/10/)**

```
.container
{
    height: 100%;
    background: pink;
    margin: -64px 0;
    padding: 64px 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content {
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;
}
header
{
    height: 64px;
    background: purple;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
footer
{
    height: 64px;
    background: gray;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Legendary! Exactly what I needed! Thanks :)

Comment: Problem is browser support!!
Chrome (any): box-sizing
Opera 8.5+: box-sizing
Firefox (any): -moz-box-sizing
Safari 3: -webkit-box-sizing (unprefixed in 5.1+ versions)
IE8+: box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

Download On this site Bootstrap.css

```
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html
```

**CSS :**

```
.modal {
        background-clip: padding-box;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        left: 21.5%;
        margin-left: -280px;
        outline: medium none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 2%;
        width: 98%;
        z-index: 1050;
    }
    .modal-footer {
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
        border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
        border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF inset;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding: 14px 15px 15px;
        text-align: left;
    }
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Modal body…</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
Modal Footer

</div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT :**
Download Javascript on bootstrap site
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.js"></script>
```

add this script on your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myModal').modal('show')
</script>
```